# Loading a new SKScene into an existing SKView messes up the bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am trying to remove a SKScene and add a new one. The first presentScene: works fine, but the second one has messed up bounds, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFTtk.png).

Here is my code.

```
@implementation GameViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadLevel:1];
}

- (void)loadLevel:(int)level {
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    [skView presentScene:nil];

    GameScene * gameScene;
    switch (level) {
        case 1:
            gameScene = [Level1 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
            break;

        case 2:
            gameScene = [Level2 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    gameScene.gameViewController = self;
    self.gameScene = gameScene;
    [skView presentScene:gameScene transition:[SKTransition crossFadeWithDuration:1.0f]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out why skView.bounds.size was changing between levels, but to correct it I hardcoded the size in. Let me know if there's a better way of doing it.

```
gameScene = [Level1 sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(768, 1024)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You run this in viewDidLoad, which means the view will be in portrait mode at that time:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadLevel:1];
}
```

To fix this, you should present the first scene in viewWillLayoutSubviews:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    if (((SKView*)self.view).scene == nil)
    {
        [self loadLevel:1];
    }
}
```

It's important to add the nil check because viewWillLayoutSubviews will be called repeatedly, for instance when rotating the device.

Comment: [self loadLevel:1] is fine, it's when Level1 calls [self.gameViewController loadLevel:2] that the weird bounds happen.

Comment: Yes, because in the first scene you may get 1024x768 as the size, and the next time it's 768x1024. Give it a try, I wouldn't be surprised if that fixes things. Or both scene may be broken after making this change, which would indicate the scene's scaleMode is not set to the desired scale mode.